# Agreement of outer measure and set function in Caratheodory's Extension Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to understand the section of the proof of Caratheodory's Extension Theorem which shows that the outer measure $\mu^*$ agrees with the defined set function $\mu$ on the algebra $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. $\mu^*(A) = \mu(A) \text{ }\forall A \in \mathcal{A}$ My notes state the following:

"Suppose $A \subseteq \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$ with $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$, given that the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ form an algebra we can assume that $A_n \subseteq A$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint."

My notes don't state it explicitly but my understanding of how to show $\mu^*(A) \geq \mu(A)$ is to argue that for any $\epsilon \geq 0$ there is a covering of $A$ where $A \subseteq \cup_n A_n$ and $\sum_n \mu(A_n) \leq \mu^*(A) + \epsilon$. We'd then use the countability property of $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}$ to conclude that $\mu(A) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$, but this is predicated on $\{A_n\}$ being a partition of $A$. This is the part I'm confused about, I don't understand why we can assume that the specific covering is a partition of $A$. More specifically, as stated above, why $A_n \subseteq A$ for all $n$.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the "countability property of $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}$"?

Comment: $\mu$ is a set function defined such that if $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a pairwise disjoint family in $\mathcal{A}$ and $A = \cup_n A_n$, then $\mu(A) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$

Comment: What guarantees $A \in \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: It is by assumption, the proof shows that $\mu^*(A) = \mu(A)$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}$. I will edit the OP to make this more clear

Comment: It's still not clear. If $\mathcal{A}$ is merely an algebra and not a sigma-algebra, then you can't assume that it is closed under countable unions.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the crux of my question. The book doesn't assert that $A = \cup_n A_n$, rather $A \subseteq \cup_n A_n$, with $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$. I don't understand the statement "given that the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ form an algebra we can assume $A_n \subseteq A$ for all $n$.